# Install 8GB RAM, get blank screen

Tags: memory

I have an Acer V5 572G - 6679

I bought an 8GB module through Crucial.com.

I tried installing it today, but when it boots up, the "on" indicator merely blinks, and the display fails to turn on.

When putting the old RAm back (1x2), the screen works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

my computer specs
6 gb ram (1x4 (soldered on), 1x2 (removable))
2 gb vram with nvidia 720m chip
windows 8.1

Comment: What is the exact model of your RAM module?

Comment: Crucial 8GB single 8GB DDR3 1600 MT/s (PC3-12800) CL11 SODIMM 204-Pin 1.35V/1.5V Notebook Memory CT102464BF160B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but either your memory stick is faulty, or possibly not compatible.  The memory you gave is not listed as compatible on Crucials website.

According to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/Acer-memory/Aspire+V5/Aspire+V5-572G-upgrades.html), the appropriate memory is DDR3 PC3-10600 CL=9 Unbuffered NON-ECC DDR3-1333 1.35 (1024Meg x 64) Part #CT4846054 (but there are a few alternatives, one of which is CT4846052 - and I can't discern the difference between that and what you bought).